# How to get PlayReady DRM Info from Android TV?

Tags: android, widevine, playready

I want to get PlayReady DRM Info from Nexus Player in Android. I have tried many methods, but they did not work. Can anyone help me? Thank you very much.

1. I looked at free application(DRM Info). It can tell me PlayReady is supported, but it cannot get vending, security level of PlayReady DRM.
2. I used MediaDrm to get DRM Info. If UUID is WideVine, it can get vending, security level of WideVine DRM. But if UUID is PlayReady, it cannot work.

> *private static final UUID PALYREADY_UUID = new UUID(0x9A04F07998404286L, 0xAB92E65BE0885F95L);*

```
@TargetApi (Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
@SuppressWarnings("ResourceType") 
private void getWVDrmInfo() {
    MediaDrm mediaDrm = null;
    try {
        mediaDrm = new MediaDrm(PALYREADY_UUID);
        String vendor = mediaDrm.getPropertyString(MediaDrm.PROPERTY_VENDOR);
        mediaDrm.release(); 
     } catch (UnsupportedSchemeException e) {
         e.printStackTrace(); 
     } 
}
```

I used this method ,but it did not work.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please post your code into your question to easily finding the problem.